# Standard way to launch a post installation step script

Tags: linux, bash

Do you know any standard way to launch automatically a custom bash script just after the installation of a Linux distro?

The bash script should run as root and can be located anywhere on the filesystem, no need for a special place.

Do I need to use init.d in some way? If so, how to prevent the relaunch of the script at every boot up?

Comment: Unclear. Are you making or modifying a distro?

Comment: Modifying a distro. My custom script ships with the distro along with all the other files and get copied on a local directory on /. Now I'm facing the problem to start automatically such script.

Comment: I would put it in /etc/init.d and have it remove itself at the end of the run.

Comment: There isn't a distro-independent way. You'd do better to ask about a specific distribution.

Comment: ok nice. I though this could be a solution however I was concerned about the safety of a self remove. Does a script get completely loaded in memory before running?

Comment: @slim: I'm using CentOS 6

Comment: It should not remove its own file, but rather remove itself from the set of active rc scripts. Otherwise the system will try to start it the next time, and complain about file not found.

Comment: "Does a script get completely loaded in memory before running?" This question is not really meaningful. Linux file system works in such a way that it is safe to remove a file open by another program. Thst program will not even notice.

Comment: @n.m: ok, that's because you unlink the file from the filesystem inode tree, the file content doesn't get erased.